# My Custom Nested SQL Query is not Working

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table named store_products in my DB.

Below Query Returns me 1

```
SELECT u_id FROM store_products WHERE p_id=1
```

I want to Get Company Details Using Above Return 1 with that Query.

So I wrote Below Query But It's not working for me.

```
SELECT * FROM reg_companies WHERE u_id = ('SELECT u_id FROM store_products WHERE p_id=1')
```

Kindly Help Me.

Comment: Don't put the sub-query in quotes...

Comment: Thanks Bro ........ !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want to do this :

```
SELECT * FROM reg_companies 
WHERE u_id IN (SELECT u_id FROM store_products WHERE p_id=1)
```

You had surrounded your nested query with quotes, which turned it into an non meaningful string.

A better approach would be a join between the 2 tables

```
SELECT C.* 
FROM reg_companies C
INNER JOIN store_products P ON C.u_id=P.u_id
WHERE P.p_id=1
```